# How can I change the colors of the filenames in the Version Control window in intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know that I can change the color of just about all texts in IntelliJ IDEA by navigating to

```
Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme
```

and then finding the item that I want to change the color of.

I have not, however, been able to find the proper name or category for the controls that would change the color of the filenames listed in the Version Control window.

I have clicked through most every option available there and although I know I missing something super simple, I have been unsuccessful.

Here is a picture to show exactly what I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings | Version Control | File Status Colors